# What is the solution of the recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$$a_n = -a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} + 4a_{n-3}$$ with $a_0 = 8$, $a_1 = 6$ and $a_2 = 26$

Comment: Have you seen any related problems?  Do you recognize the relationship between your problem and the polynomial $x^3 = -x^2+4x+4$ and in particular the roots of that polynomial?

Comment: This is not a "do my homework, NOW!" site, sorry!

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand the polynomial and the roots, but not how it relates to the problem.

Comment: The closed form for a linear recurrence can be expressed as a sum of exponentials. The roots of the characteristic polynomial are the bases for these exponentials (note that the constant multipliers are not determined by the polynomial).

Comment: Can you take it from here?

Comment: @JoshuaWang This helped thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz I had not come across the Characteristic Root Technique, so this helped guide me there, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to view if you're stuck

> The characteristic polynomial is:
>
>  $$r^{3} + r^{2} - 4r - 4 = 0$$
>
>  This can be factored as:
>
>  $$(r+1)(r+2)(r-2) = 0$$
>
>  Thus, $a_{n}$ can be expressed as:
>
>  $$a_{n} = \alpha (-1)^{n} + \beta (-2)^{n} + \gamma (2)^{n}$$
>
>  For some real $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$. Using the initial values, we
>  must then solve the system of equations:
>
>  $$a_{0} = \alpha + \beta + \gamma = 8$$
>
>  $$a_{1} = -\alpha -2\beta + 2\gamma = 6$$
>
>  $$a_{2} = \alpha + 4\beta + 4\gamma = 26$$
>
>  Adding the first $2$ and the last $2$ equations gives us:
>
>  $$-\beta + 3\gamma = 14$$
>
>  $$2\beta + 6\gamma = 32$$
>
>  Solving, we get $\beta = 1, \gamma = 5$. Thus, $\alpha = 2$, and
>  $$\boxed{a_{n} = 2(-1)^{n} + (-2)^{n} + 5(2)^{n}.}$$